# Visual c++ how to read from rich text box

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, richtextbox, line-by-line

I am trying to read from a rich text box line by line in Visual c++ but don't know how to do it.
Can anyone provide a small example of how it works? I am really new to visual studio and Visual C++.
What I would like to do,is to store each line from the rich text box in a string,using a for loop.
Let's say in the rich text box I have:
text1
text2
text3
The for loop will pretty much read each line,and than I will do other operations with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say what kind of rich text box you are actually using.

If you are using the .NET [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) class, you can iterate through its [`Lines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property:

```
array<String^>^ lines = textBox->Lines;
int count = lines->Length;

for (int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx)
{
    // use lines[idx] as needed...
}
```

If you are using the MFC [`CRichEditCtrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76a787xf.aspx) class, you can call its [`GetLineCount()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0d8ycez.aspx), [`LineLength()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab6bbhw8.aspx), and [`GetLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z83tcz.aspx) methods:

```
int count = textBox.GetLineCount();

for (int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx)
{
    std::basic_string<TCHAR> line;

    int len = textBox.LineLength(idx);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        line.resize(len+1);
        len = textBox.GetLine(idx, &line[0], len);
        line.resize(len);
    }

    // use line as needed...
}
```

If you are using the Win32 [`Rich Edit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605.aspx) control, you can send it [`EM_GETLINECOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761586.aspx), [`EM_LINELENGTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761613.aspx), and [`EM_GETLINE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761584.aspx) messages:

```
int count = SendMessage(hTextBox, EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0);

for (int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx)
{
    std::basic_string<TCHAR> line;

    int len = SendMessage(hTextBox, EM_LINELENGTH, idx, 0);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        line.resize(len+1);
        *(reinterpret_cast<WORD*>(&line[0])) = (WORD)len;
        len = SendMessage(hTextBox, EM_GETLINE, idx, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&line[0]));
        line.resize(len);
    }

    // use line as needed...
}
```

Comment: Im getting this error when trying to add the extracted string from the rich box to a file:binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion. I am using this commad file  << lines[idx] << endl;

Comment: I am using a ,NET rich box,and the example is working,tried it with a simple message box,but I get that error when trying to write it like this "file << lines[idx]<<endl;

Comment: Now that we have established that you are using .NET (C++-CLI?), there is no `<<` operator defined for a `String^` pointer, and even if you dereference the pointer (which you would have to) there is no `<<` operator defined for a `String` value, either. Besides, such an operator would not work anyway unless `file` is defined as a `std::wofstream` or other `wchar_t` based output stream, as `String` uses `wchar_t` characters. In that case, you can iterate the string's [`Chars[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx) property, writing each `wchar_t` to the stream...

Comment: ..., but, if you are using `std::ofstream` or other `char`-based stream, you will have to convert the `String` data to a byte array using the [`GetBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx) method of [`System.Text.Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) and then you can write those values to your stream as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much man,and yes I am using std::ofstream since I am used to it,and as you probably figured out,I am a new to programming.I will try to convert it and will tell you if I managed to do it.Thanks so much again.All of this is new to me

Comment: For future reference, please always indicate the actual language/framework you are using, and what you are trying to accomplish.  In this case, there are big differences between .NET and Win32, between looping a RichEdit's lines and writing those values to a stream, etc.  Please be more specific in the future.

Comment: I have managed to fix it using marshal_context.Thank you so much again for all the help.